# Configured my company mail id to my Personal mail address

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I have configured to make the mails from my company mail id to be retrieved in my Personal mail address(gmail).
Here I dont know is there any possibility for my management members to access my Personal mail. Before they have configured my company mail id in thunderbird.

Comment: How did you configure this? Is your company mail an Exchange, did you forward to Gmail?

Comment: @Kathir: it is impossible to answer your question in its current form. Your general use of "configured" leaves us guessing exactly what the situation is. Please update your question with more details and try to explain exactly what it is that you did. Any answers until then will be speculative "If...... then.....". Some people might think you set up email forwarding from one account to another... others may think you did something else. It's not clear at all.

Comment: Any email sent to your company's mail server can be read by your company.  They will be unable to access your personal email account.  Although if they discover your doing this you will likely be fired since you know have company information on a personal account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your company IT department set up your Thunderbird for you, using your username/password, then they definitely have full access to your account. Even if you entered your own login details, if this was set up on your work-owned computer then they might have remote access to the machine whenever they want, so they could still view and send/receive from your account.

I tend to think it's best to keep work and personal accounts separate, and this is a pretty good example of why. You also might have certain contractual obligations to give up any work-related data/emails/contacts when you leave the company, so having these in your personal accounts really muddies the waters.

Comment: Thanks and now I deleted the configured mail from my personal mail id, Still there any possibility of making issues by my management.